# Get Device Properties using Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i'm designing a cross platform app using xamarin forms.
every page/view/Form designed from code behind. now i want to read Height and Width of the device used by user. based on those values, i want to place some header and footers.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To get the screen width (or height) within a Xamarin.Forms solution, I usually add the following few lines of code:

1. Define a public static property in the shared code, preferably in `App.cs`:

   ```cs
   static public int ScreenWidth;
   ```
2. Initialize it for iOS at the beginning of `FinishedLaunching` in `AppDelegate.cs`:

   ```cs
   App.ScreenWidth = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
   ```
3. Initialize it for Android in `OnCreate` of `MainActivity.cs` (as described [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/device_specific/detect_screen_size/))

   ```cs
   App.ScreenWidth = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
   ```

   (By dividing by the density this yields device independent pixels.)

I didn't work with Windows Phone, but there should be an equivalent command. And of course, getting the screen height works similarly.

Now you can access `App.ScreenWidth` anywhere in your code.

Comment: I would add a comparison between width and height in case we are in landscape mode

Answer (score 2):

In **Xamarin Forms Labs** [here](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) there are classes and examples for getting **Device** screen information like what you are after.

There are some further notes on implementing this and getting the **Device** object that you require [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22583/xamarin-forms-screensize).

On a different note, if your only on about placing **Headers** and **Footers** then why not use the inbuilt **Xamarin.Forms** controls to auto-expand **controls** and **layouts** etc, that will adapt automatically based to screen of the user's device?

I get the impression that you are looking to go down an **AbsoluteLayout** approach and specify values yourself?  If so, there really is no need.  Especially for Headers and Footers of a Layout?

Answer (score 1):

I do this in my viewmodel and it works great.  You could do the same in your code-behind.

```
public SomeViewModel
{
    private double width;
    private double Width
    {
        get { return width; }
        set
        {
            width = value;
            if (value != 0 && value != -1)
            {
                // device width found, set other properties
                SetProperties();
            }
        }
    }

    void SetProperties()
    {
        // use value of Width however you need
    }

    public SomeViewModel()
    {
         Width = Application.Current.MainPage.Width;
         var fireAndForget = Task.Run(GetWidthAsync);
    }

    public async Task GetWidthAsync()
    {
        while (Width == -1 || Width == 0)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)).ConfigureAwait(false);
            // MainPage is the page that is using this ViewModel
            Width = Application.Current.MainPage.Width;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to display Width in a label in your form for testing purposes using binding, don't forget to change the property from private to public.