# Xamarin Form: What is the width/height meaning returned from onSizeAllocated?

Tags: xamarin, view, grid, xamarin.forms

I have a contentView which cover the whole galaxy s4 screen. When I debug in onSizeAllocated it return 680 * 335 around that amount. My device screen should be more than that.

I wanted to know the width of the screen so I can evenly distributed a square image in a grid.

Comment: For the size in Xamarin.Forms (PCL/Shared), it equals pixels in iOS, dp in Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary:
These sizes are not pixels. Instead, they are device-independent units recognised independently by each platform.

Check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05).

Answer (score 0):

What `onSizeAllocated` is returning is a internal representation of size managed by Xamarin.Forms. Its not the current pixels of your device.

To get the current screen size, you have a lot of options, but i will put it here some pointers to get there.

1 - On [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465513/how-to-get-detect-screen-size-in-xamarin-forms), [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543063/get-device-properties-using-xamarin-forms)

2 - With [Xlabs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Device)

3 - Recent [plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.XamJam.Screen/1.0.5)

Comment: Thanks .. I tried to find the Xlabs on nuget in Xamarin Studio but couldn't find it. Therefore I add Scorchio.NinjaCoder.Xamarin.Forms.Labs 2.0.0 and get the dependency from that. I think the xlabs added into my project is not the latest and I can't update it.

Comment: @Simon search for "XLabs.Forms" in the nuget packages manager.